# document on load JQuery confusion

Tags: visualforce, jquery

Can someone explain the difference between

```
$(document).ready(function($){

});
```

and

```
$(function(){

});
```

All of the info that I have seen online says that they are identical... however, when I am using them in a Visualforce page, the following works and I don't get any issues:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $.cometd.init({
        url: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/cometd/24.0/',
        requestHeaders: {
            Authorization: 'OAuth {!$Api.Session_ID}'
        }
    });
});
```

However when I change it to:

```
$(function() {
    $.cometd.init({
        url: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/cometd/24.0/',
        requestHeaders: {
            Authorization: 'OAuth {!$Api.Session_ID}'
        }
    });
});
```

I get an error... Also when I have an onClick function it works with `$(function() {});` but doesn't work with `$(document).ready(function($){})`

Comment: The documentation that declares them equivalent doesn't pass $ as an argument to the function. But I can't explain if/why that might make a difference.